# Find all timezone offset periods between two timezones

Tags: c#, date, timezone, dst

I have code that will give me the offset in seconds between a destination timezone and source timezone, for all periods between two dates.

The following code will do this:

```
// example start and end date
DateTime startDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Now.Date, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
DateTime endDate = startDate.AddYears(10);

// the timezones to use
var sourceZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time");
var destinationZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Mountain Standard Time");

// the periods and timezone offsets
var results = new List<Tuple<DateTime, DateTime, double>>();

// loop variables
DateTime currentDate = startDate;
DateTime periodStartDate = currentDate;

// the current period offset (in seconds)
double? currentOffset = null;

while (currentDate < endDate)
{
    DateTime destTime;

    // if the current time is invalid for the source timezone
    // then advance time until it is not invalid
    while (sourceZone.IsInvalidTime(currentDate))
        currentDate = currentDate.AddMinutes(30d);

    destTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(currentDate, sourceZone, destinationZone);

    // calculate the offset for this iteration
    double iterationOffset = destTime.Subtract(currentDate).TotalSeconds;

    if (currentOffset == null)
        // the current offset is null so use the iteration offset
        currentOffset = iterationOffset;
    else if (iterationOffset != currentOffset.Value)
    {
        // the current offset doesn't equal the iteration offset
        // that means that a period has been identified

        // add the period to the list
        results.Add(Tuple.Create(periodStartDate, currentDate, currentOffset.Value));

        // the start of the period is the new current date
        periodStartDate = currentDate;

        // the current offset becomes the iteration offset
        currentOffset = iterationOffset;
    }

    // increment the day by 30 minutes
    currentDate = currentDate.AddMinutes(30d);
}

foreach (var item in results)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", item.Item1, item.Item2, item.Item3);
```

Results:

```
╔═══════════════════════╦═══════════════════════╦════════╗
║      PeriodStart      ║       PeriodEnd       ║ Offset ║
╠═══════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬════════╣
║ 7/13/2015 12:00:00 AM ║ 10/25/2015 1:00:00 AM ║ -25200 ║
║ 10/25/2015 1:00:00 AM ║ 11/1/2015 8:00:00 AM  ║ -21600 ║
║ 11/1/2015 8:00:00 AM  ║ 3/13/2016 9:00:00 AM  ║ -25200 ║
║ 3/13/2016 9:00:00 AM  ║ 3/27/2016 2:00:00 AM  ║ -21600 ║
║ 3/27/2016 2:00:00 AM  ║ 10/30/2016 1:00:00 AM ║ -25200 ║
║ 10/30/2016 1:00:00 AM ║ 11/6/2016 8:00:00 AM  ║ -21600 ║
║ 11/6/2016 8:00:00 AM  ║ 3/12/2017 9:00:00 AM  ║ -25200 ║
║ 3/12/2017 9:00:00 AM  ║ 3/26/2017 2:00:00 AM  ║ -21600 ║
║ 3/26/2017 2:00:00 AM  ║ 10/29/2017 1:00:00 AM ║ -25200 ║
║ 10/29/2017 1:00:00 AM ║ 11/5/2017 8:00:00 AM  ║ -21600 ║
║ 11/5/2017 8:00:00 AM  ║ 3/11/2018 9:00:00 AM  ║ -25200 ║
║          ...          ║          ...          ║   ...  ║
╚═══════════════════════╩═══════════════════════╩════════╝
```

Now while this seems to work, I know that it is not the most efficient way to do it. I'm basically stuck on converting this to a method that doesn't have to use hard-coded time increments to find all these periods where a change in offset occurs.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using NodaTime;

...

// Get some time zones.  You can use Tzdb or Bcl zones here.
DateTimeZone sourceZone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Bcl["GMT Standard Time"]; // London
DateTimeZone destinationZone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Bcl["Mountain Standard Time"]; // Denver

// Determine the period of time we're interested in evaluating.
// I'm taking today in the source time zone, up to 10 years in the future.
Instant now = SystemClock.Instance.Now;
Instant start = sourceZone.AtStartOfDay(now.InZone(sourceZone).Date).ToInstant();
Instant end = start.InZone(sourceZone).LocalDateTime.PlusYears(10).InZoneLeniently(sourceZone).ToInstant();

// Get the intervals for our each of the zones over these periods
var sourceIntervals = sourceZone.GetZoneIntervals(start, end);
var destinationIntervals = destinationZone.GetZoneIntervals(start, end);

// Find all of the instants we care about, including the start and end points,
// and all transitions from either zone in between
var instants = sourceIntervals.Union(destinationIntervals)
    .SelectMany(x => new[] {x.Start, x.End})
    .Union(new[] {start, end})
    .OrderBy(x => x).Distinct()
    .Where(x => x >= start && x < end)
    .ToArray();

// Loop through the instants
for (int i = 0; i < instants.Length -1; i++)
{
    // Get this instant and the next one
    Instant instant1 = instants[i];
    Instant instant2 = instants[i + 1];

    // convert each instant to the source zone
    ZonedDateTime zdt1 = instant1.InZone(sourceZone);
    ZonedDateTime zdt2 = instant2.InZone(sourceZone);

    // Get the offsets for instant1 in each zone 
    Offset sourceOffset = zdt1.Offset;
    Offset destOffset = destinationZone.GetUtcOffset(instant1);

    // Calc the difference between the offsets
    int deltaSeconds = (destOffset.Milliseconds - sourceOffset.Milliseconds)/1000;

    // Convert to the same types you had in your example (optional)
    DateTime dt1 = zdt1.ToDateTimeUnspecified();
    DateTime dt2 = zdt2.ToDateTimeUnspecified();

    // emit output
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", dt1, dt2, deltaSeconds);
}
```

Note that the output is identical to your own, *except* for the first date.  Yours gave `7/13/2015` when I ran it, and mine gave `7/14/2015`.  This is because your code has a bug, in that your starting date is not based on today in the source time zone, but instead it starts with today in the *local* time zone.

Also, I assumed you wanted all output to be in terms of the *source* time zone, since that's what your example gave.

Additionally, you may want to consider that the output isn't particularly clear with regard to the transitions in the source zone.  During a fall-back transition you can't tell *which* of the two times the output represents, and during a spring-forward transition it's not clear where the *gap* actually is.  A `DateTimeOffset` output would be much clearer in this regard.